# why cannot use the double pointer as the return type in function head?

Tags: c++, csv

I'm not sure how to handle the bug for the double pointer as the return type in function head.

The code like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<sstream>
#include<string>

int noodrows();
int noodcols();
string** genMatrix(int rows, int cols);

using namespace std;

void main() {
    //ifstream file("test.txt");
    int rows, cols;
    rows = noodrows();
    cols = noodcols();
    cout << "no of rows are: " << rows << "\t";
    cout << "no of cols are: " << cols << "\t";
    string** matrix = genMatrix(rows, cols);

}

int noodcols() {
    //get the colume for the csv.
    ifstream file3("D:\\Final-Year-Project-master\\FYP\\station_matrix.csv");
    string data;
    int counter = 0;
    getline(file3, data);
    stringstream sstream(data);
    while (!sstream.eof()) {
        getline(sstream, data, ',');
        counter++;
    }
    return counter;
}

int noodrows() {
    //get the row for the csv
    ifstream file2("D:\\Final-Year-Project-master\\FYP\\station_matrix.csv");
    if (!file2.is_open()) {
        cout << "cannot open the file!" << endl;

    }

    string data;
    int counter = 0;

    while (getline(file2, data)) {
        cout << data << endl;
        counter++;
    }
    return counter;
}

string** genMatrix(int rows, int cols) {
    string** matrix = new string * [rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        matrix[i] = new string[cols];
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

And the error report like this:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: csv, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>C:\Users\Tyler.Tuo\source\repos\csv\csv\csv.cpp(7,7): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'
1>C:\Users\Tyler.Tuo\source\repos\csv\csv\csv.cpp(7,7): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Users\Tyler.Tuo\source\repos\csv\csv\csv.cpp(7,39): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Users\Tyler.Tuo\source\repos\csv\csv\csv.cpp(13,13): warning C4326: return type of 'main' should be 'int' instead of 'void'
1>C:\Users\Tyler.Tuo\source\repos\csv\csv\csv.cpp(20,8): error C2872: 'string': ambiguous symbol
1>C:\Users\Tyler.Tuo\source\repos\csv\csv\csv.cpp(7,1): message : could be 'int string'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include\xstring(4471,7): message : or       'std::string'
1>C:\Users\Tyler.Tuo\source\repos\csv\csv\csv.cpp(20,11): error C2065: 'matrix': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\Tyler.Tuo\source\repos\csv\csv\csv.cpp(28,9): error C2872: 'string': ambiguous symbol
1>C:\Users\Tyler.Tuo\source\repos\csv\csv\csv.cpp(7,1): message : could be 'int string'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include\xstring(4471,7): message : or       'std::string'
1>C:\Users\Tyler.Tuo\source\repos\csv\csv\csv.cpp(28,13): error C2872: 'string': ambiguous symbol
1>C:\Users\Tyler.Tuo\source\repos\csv\csv\csv.cpp(7,1): message : could be 'int string'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include\xstring(4471,7): message : or       'std::string'
1>C:\Users\Tyler.Tuo\source\repos\csv\csv\csv.cpp(28,9): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'data'
1>C:\Users\Tyler.Tuo\source\repos\csv\csv\csv.cpp(28,9): warning C4551: function call missing argument list
1>C:\Users\Tyler.Tuo\source\repos\csv\csv\csv.cpp(30,2): error C2672: 'getline': no matching overloaded function found
```

I'm now studying how to use c++ processing the csv file and the tutorial code for the function of genMatrix is correct. But I don't know why my machine cannot compile it. The synatx for thr head file and the function are both correct. 
The program is fine when I delete the line of string** matrix = genMatrix(rows, cols);

Comment: Suggest `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>` and let the compiler handle the memory management rather than using `new[]/delete[]`. And see [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/364696)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write

```
std::string** genMatrix(int rows, int cols) {
```

string is a std(standard template library for c++ witch is Optional to use) type si you need the namespace and the header file included (witch you have already included) .

i personally don't prefer using `using namespace std;` in global scope to not mix types in different namespaces and to make better readable code  so here's the better way

Answer (score 1):

You declare

```
string** genMatrix(int rows, int cols);
```

before you are `using namespace std`. Thus, at this point compiler does not know what a `string` is. Just swap these lines.

Answer (score 1):

`using namespace std;` need to be before the define of genMatrix. The function return string, but string is not defined yet.